# Python 3 Print output from try statement on the same line and I am trying to learn threading

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import time
import threading
import urllib.request

def message(msg):
    print(time.strftime('[%H:%M:%S]'), msg)


def check(proxy):
    proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https':proxy})
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    message("Trying => "+proxy)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com", timeout=5)
        print("Working")
        with open("CheckedProxies.txt", "a") as appe:
            appe.write(proxy.replace("\n","") + "\n")
    except:
        print("Not Working")
        pass

try:
    proxies = open("/home/zion/Desktop/proxies.txt", "r").readlines()
except:
    message("File Empty Exiting!")
    exit()

if proxies == "":
    print("File Empty, Enter Proxies")

newtxt = open("CheckedProxies.txt","w")
message("~ Loading "+ str(len(proxies)) +" Proxies!")
time.sleep(1)
for proxy in proxies:
    check(proxy)
os.exit(CTRL-C)
message("Done Checking Proxies!")
```

I am trying to get the Not working to print on the same line as Trying proxy....my current output is:

> [23:20:51] ~ Loading 1598 Proxies!
>
> [23:20:52] Trying => 1.0.135.34:8080
>
> Not Working
>   [23:20:53] Trying => 1.10.236.214:8080
>
> Not Working
>   [23:20:53] Trying => 103.122.255.18:8080

I am trying to get it to print like this

> [23:20:53] Trying => 127.0.0.1:8080  Not Working!

I have tried to "print("Not Working", end='')"
but it prints out like this``

> Not Working[23:07:30] Trying => 1.10.236.214:8080

I am not sure how to get the Not working to print after the trying and proxy....

I am also trying to learn how to use the threading module but am having trouble....
I want my program to open multiple threads testing my proxys... thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to threading, the best way to do it here is to use a Multiprocessing Pool.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

And then instead of:

```py
for proxy in proxies:
    check(proxy)
```

Use:

```py
p=Pool(5)
p.map(check,proxies)
```

For making them all on one line, I would add the outputs to a string, then at the end of the function print it out.

Comment: Yes, but instead of printing them all at different times, I would do something like "output+= 'Trying => '+proxy", then at the end of the function, print all of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the printing, it seems that you want to print without an automatic newline and you  have worked out to use `end`

```
print("Hello ", end = '')
print("World! ")
```

you say

> I have tried to "print("Not Working", end='')" but it prints out like
>   this``

but it seems to me that the problematic print() is in

```
def message(msg):
```

Comment: so if i get rid of my def message(msg): function than i should be able to print on the same line? let me try that and as far as the multiprocessing goes I think I need to put some sort of print lock? cause it seems like its printing out the trying proxy and working/not working at the same time.... I kinda of wanted it to print out the trying proxies like 50 at a time and than when done testing them to print the working/not working on the side of the trying statements

Comment: what i meant was use end="" in the print in your message function. This is the source of unwanted new line, isn't it?